# What's the correct way to deploy a Web API and MVC project to Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have both an ASP.net Web API and MVC project that I am trying to deploy to an Azure Web App. I can deploy either one by themselves, but the one will overwrite the other. I do have the web deploy dialog set to target the same URL when I deploy each one. Obviously I am doing it wrong. How can I deploy both projects to the same Azure web app? Or do I need to create two different web apps in the same resource group? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you are trying to deploy essentially 2 projects to the same Azure Wesbite?

1x MVC Website

1x WebAPI

It is indeed possible to deploy an MVC Website and a WebAPI to a single Azure Wesbite, but there's a little bit of work to do around this, using Virtual Directories in the Azure Websites configuration.

[This MSDN Blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/) outlines all the steps you need to do to make this work. I have used it many times for this exact scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'correct way'. There are many ways of deploying an asp.net web api and mvc to Azure. One way of doing it is working with staging environments. You basically deploy to a separate deployment slot and if all is oke, swat it with the production slot.

[msdn: web-sites-staged-publishing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/)